# javascript multiple inputs from controls

Tags: c#, javascript, controls

I have something like this

```
<button onclick="JavascriptFunction();">HTTPPost Button</button>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function JavascriptFunction() {
    var url = '@Url.Action("PostMethod")';
    var data = $('input[name="MyTextBlock"]').serialize();
    $("#divLoading").show();
    $.post(url, data,
            function (data) {
                $("#PID")[0].innerHTML = data;
                $("#divLoading").hide();
            });
}
</script>
```

in which I want to pass in multiple controls (including textboxes and dropdowns) how can I add that into var data? Thanks.  I should also mention that MyTextBlock is a TextBox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line,

```
var data = $('input[name="MyTextBlock"]').serialize();
```

you can include all of the elements you want to serialize into the query string. For example, if your dropdown had the id `dropdown`, you could do this:

```
var data = $('#dropdown, input[name="MyTextBlock"]').serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to use [`.serializeArray`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) rather than `.serialize`, it turns your form into an array rather than a string. You can call `.serializeArray` on an entire form to get the whole contents.